# Consequences of Ker(f)=Im(f)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose we have a Endomorphism on a   Vectorspace $V$  whose Kernel is equal to its image:

Since $\textrm{Ker}(f)=f^{-1}(0_{V})$ and $\textrm{Im}(f)=f(V)$ wouldn't that imply, that V can only be equal to ${0_{V}}$ ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What about $(x,y)\mapsto (y,0)$ in two dimensions?

Comment: Thank you, if you would  post this as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Im$(f) = \{ x\in V: \exists y\in V, f(y)=x\}$ then if Im$(f)=$Ker$(f)$, $\forall x\in V$, $f^2(x)=0$ and $f^2$ is the null function over $V$ but that does not imply anything about $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One consequence of $ \operatorname{im}(f) =\ker(f)$ is that $\dim V$ is even because $\dim V = \dim \ker(f) + \dim \operatorname{im}(f)$.

More generally, we have

> $ \operatorname{im}(f) \subseteq \ker(f)$ iff $f^2=0$

There are $f\ne0$ such that $f^2=0$ in every even dimension. Just take$V=\mathbb R^{2n}$ and the matrix with $n$ diagonal blocks $\pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}$.